# sharepoint designer workflow not available for other users to manually start

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I created a SharePoint Designer List workflow and Published it to the library. I am able to run that manually. But it is not available for any of the users other than me. They are not able to see those workflows even in SharePoint designer.

Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users need "Contribute" and "Approve" permissions for this list. 
You can do this setting by following the 
List Settings --> Permissions For This List